# Bucle de insertar id no repetida en un ArrayList

Tags: java

Este método básicamente realiza una comprobación de si una id está repetida y lanza un error.

Pero tiene un error: al entrar una id repetida, tengo más oportunidades (pide una nueva idea y la ingreso), pero si vuelvo a entrar de nuevo la misma, pasa como cierta.

¿Alguien sabe por qué o en qué fallo?

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
   if (lista.get(i).getidGeneral() != idGeneral) {
    } else {
        while (lista.get(i).getidGeneral() == idGeneral) {

            try {
                throw new DuplicateVehicleException("La id ya esta en uso");
            } catch (DuplicateVehicleException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Introduce una nueva id:");
            idGeneral = lec.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No pongas el codigo en comentarios, edita la pregunta y ponlo alli.

Comment: ya esta, alguien la ha editado gracias!

Comment: ¿Que vale lista al entrar?

Comment: lista es una ArrayList

Comment: No pregunto que es, sino que vale.

Comment: @user50489 porque cuando ingresa una nueva id (o la misma), deberías recorrer el ArrayList desde el inicio para verificarlo... Estoy seguro que alguien más va a responder con más detalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas lanzando la excepción siempre que entre.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) { 
  if (lista.get(i).getidGeneral() != idGeneral) {
    // Este if vacio no debería estar.
  } else { 
    while (lista.get(i).getidGeneral() == idGeneral) { 
      try { 
        // estas haciendo que siempre lanza esta excepción.
        throw new DuplicateVehicleException("La id ya esta en uso");  
      } catch (DuplicateVehicleException e) { 
        // Aquí siempre coges la excepción y se acabo el programa.
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
        System.out.println("Introduce una nueva id:"); 
        idGeneral = lec.nextInt(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Te pongo un ejemplo, con el que, aunque encuentre algo repetido, sigue recorriendo el bucle.
Prueba con esto:

```
boolean flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) { 
  if(lista.get(i).getidGeneral() == idGeneral){
    flag = true;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Introduce una nueva id:"); 
    idGeneral = lec.nextInt(); 
  }
}
if(flag){
  throw new DuplicateVehicleException("Se ha intentado añadir una id en uso.");
}
```

En caso de que quieras que se interrumpa todo en caso de que encuentre un repetido.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) { 
  if(lista.get(i).getidGeneral() == idGeneral){
    throw new DuplicateVehicleException("El id esta repetido");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Introduce una nueva id:"); 
    idGeneral = lec.nextInt(); 
  }
}
```

De todos modos, es un tanto lioso, intenta explicar que quieres conseguir, a ver si te puedo ayudar mejor.

Un saludo.

Comment: De ser así le he malentendido.

Comment: :S no entiendo jaja osea, que cuando mete un nuevo "id" lo tiene que comprobar contra todo el array de ids (lista) no? y ese funcionamiento se supone que esta mal?
Creo que primero debería resolver problemas como el while infinito, o lanzar un throw nada mas entrar en un while (que es lo que le evita el bucle infinito). Porque tal como esta no es nada claro.

Comment: Si es como mencionas, el error no me parece estar en esta porción de código, sino donde "pida" el nuevo id. 
Estaría guay que pusiera algo más del código, por ver donde puede estar el error.

Answer (score 3):

ya lo he conseguido el problema que me han contado es que sigue la Array desde donde esta es como si tuviese un "vacio" en el bucle no se explicarlo soy novato..la cosa es que en un metodo y pasandole por paramtro la id no me hace ese vacio Gracias a todoos!!

```
private void compruebaId (int idGeneral) throws DuplicateVehicleException{

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        if (lista.get(i).getidGeneral() == idGeneral) {
            throw new DuplicateVehicleException("La id ya esta en uso");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Eso que estás describiendo como "vacío", significa que en la pregunta estabas intentando ver si un id existe, pero verificando desde donde te habías quedado con la anterior, no desde el inicio.

Comment: si exacto! Justo eso!